# Wait for asynchronous methods in a loop to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a C# program that currently downloads data from several sites synchronously after which the code does some work on the data I've downloaded. I am trying to move this to do my downloads asynchronously and then process the data I've downloaded. I am having some trouble with this sequencing. Below is a snapshot of code I am using:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started URL downloader");
        UrlDownloader d = new UrlDownloader();
        d.Process();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished URL downloader");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class UrlDownloader
{
    public void Process()
    {
        List<string> urls = new List<string>() { 
            "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
            "http://www.microsoft.com", 
            "http://www.apple.com", 
            "http://www.google.com" 
        };

        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            WebClient Wc = new WebClient();
            Wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(DownloadDataAsync);
            Uri varUri = new Uri(url);
            Wc.OpenReadAsync(varUri, url);
        }
    }

    void DownloadDataAsync(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader k = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        string temp = k.ReadToEnd();
        PrintWebsiteTitle(temp, e.UserState as string);
    }

    void PrintWebsiteTitle(string temp, string source)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"<title[^>]*>(.*)</title[^>]*>");
        string title = reg.Match(temp).Groups[1].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 10));
        Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}, Title: {1}", source, title);
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 10));
    }
}
```

Essentially, my problem is this. My output from above is:

```
Started URL downloader
Finished URL downloader
"Results of d.Process()"
```

What I want to do is complete the d.Process() method and then return to the "Main" method in my Program class. So, the output I am looking for is:

```
Started URL downloader
"Results of d.Process()"
Finished URL downloader
```

My d.Process() method runs asynchronously, but I can't figure out how to wait for all of my processing to complete before returning to my Main method. Any ideas on how to do this in C#4.0? I am not sure how I'd go about 'telling' my Process() method to wait until all it's asynchronous activity is complete before returning to the Main method.

Comment: multiple questions exist regarding asynchronous operations: one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906778/how-to-wait-on-multiple-asynchronous-operation-completion

Comment: What version of C# are you using? .Net 4.0 provides the TPL using the Task object.

Comment: You could just do OpenRead, which does it synchronously and blocks the current thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on .NET>=4.0 you can use TPL

```
Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
{
    WebClient Wc = new WebClient();
    string page = Wc.DownloadString(url);
    PrintWebsiteTitle(page);
 });
```

I would also use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the page instead of regex.

```
void PrintWebsiteTitle(string page)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").First().InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @L.B this works great! I'm new to asynchronous programming so wasn't familiar with TPL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190) instead of writing your own.  You could then use the Task Parallel Library to wrap the call to DownloadDataAsync in a TaskCompletionSource to get multiple Task objects you can wait on or continue with:

```
        webClient.DownloadDataAsync(myUri);
        webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                           {
                                            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
                                           };

        if (wait)
        {
            tcs.Task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("got {0} bytes", tcs.Task.Result.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.Task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("got {0} bytes", t.Result.Length));
        }
```

To handle error conditions, you can expand the use of the TaskCompletionSource:

```
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                {
                           if(e.Error != null) tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                           else if(e.Cancelled) tcs.SetCanceled();
                           else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
                                 };
```

To do similar with multiple tasks:

```
Task.WaitAll(tcs.Task, tcs2.Task);
```

or

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[] {tcs.Task, tcs2.Task}, ts =>
                                                    {
                                                        /* do something with all the results */
                                                    });
```